# Missing site design templates in GUI when creating new site

Tags: sharepoint-online

All of our custom site designs still exists (Have check with powershell) but I can no longer choose them from the GUI when creting a new site..
Anyone have seen this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per the latest standard release during July - Aug 2021 in relation to Microsoft new feature is associated with Microsoft 365 [Roadmap ID 70574](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=70574)  we no longer have the ability to apply site Templates/designs in the SharePoint admin center while new site creation.

Before the recent release from Microsoft,  site designs were applied to SharePoint sites at the point of site creation.
Following this new release the “choose a design” for selection site design option is no longer present for team or communication sites through the SharePoint admin center.

In Order to apply Site design, you have to use the "Apply site template" option under the site setting menu after site creation.

**How to apply site design**

1. We need to apply site design/Template after site creation, This option is available under the site setting menu option

[image]

2. From the "select a template" pop up screen  choose the desired
   template
3. Click on "Use Template" button

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that I cannot reproduced this issue on my development tenant.
[image]

However, I can reproduce it on my another tenant.
[image]

I didn't find any roadmap which says Microsoft will disable Choose a design menu. As a workaround, you can create a site firstly and apply a published site design to the new site collection using PowerShell command [Invoke-SPOSiteDesign](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/invoke-spositedesign?view=sharepoint-ps) or PnP [Invoke-PnPSiteDesign](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/invoke-pnpsitedesign?view=sharepoint-ps).

Examples:

```
Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity 501z8c32-4147-44d4-8607-26c2f67cae82 -WebUrl "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/projectgo"

or

Invoke-PnPSiteDesign -Identity 5c73382d-9643-4aa0-9160-d0cba35e40fd -WebUrl "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/mydemosite"
```

You can also go to Microsoft 365 admin center to **new a service request** to confirm it with Microsoft.